# Codeigniter Blank Screen - Failing to load welcome class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am in the process of migrating codeigniter from centos to ubuntu and after moving the files, adjusting the config files, etc, I am getting the white screen of death. Debugging it, the code seems to die in CodeIgniter.php at

```
$CI = new $class();
```

where

```
$class = welcome
```

I have confirmed the MySQL is installed and running, both in PHP and on the command line. Additionally, I can't find codeigniter complaining about any errors in either my apache error logs or the codeigniter ones at application/logs. This is despite setting the logging threshold to 4 and setting display errors to true.

Comment: What is the status code of the response ?

Comment: What is the PHP version (`php -v` in terminal or `echo PHP_VERSION;` in script)?

Comment: echo PHP_VERSION outputs: 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4. In the console it says 500

Comment: If it is a 500 error, your `/var/log/apache2/error.log` should have saved this

Answer (score 0):

the only solution for this issue to find the php error logs,
check it on /var/logs/apache2/errors.log or if you use ssl /var/logs/apache2/ssl_errors.log
this is the default paths for php error log

please check your php error logs for getting the error message.

Answer (score 0):

There's 3 solutions to know where's the problem.
1- Codeigniter offer logs for configure it

- go to application/config.php
- Change `$config['log_threshold'] = 2; //for debug messages`
- Each request you can find the log messages in

> application/logs/..

or

> system/logs/..

Don't forget to switch it off after fix your issue by change it to 0 or 1 for display error messages only.

2- Or you can Enable development mode but i prefer the first solution.

- if you want to switch to development mode edit index.php in the main project files and change `ENVIRONMENT`  definition to `'development'`
  this option show errors on the site front.

3- Or you can check the PHP log errors in

> /var/log/apache2/error.log

or

> /var/log/apache2/ssl_error.log

if you using https